# Routing only the private network in wireguard VPN

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, wireguard

I have a few hosts behind a NAT router that I want to access via a wireguard VPN. I could successfully configure the private network, but there's still something that baffles me.

I want each peer to:

- access each other (`172.9.9.*`) via the VPN (via `wg0`)
- access every other host outside the VPN (via `eth0`).

Here's a schema of the network and current configuration:

```
┌─────┐    ┌──────────┐    ┌─────┐
│  S  ├────┤ Internet ├────┤  A  │
└─────┘    └───┬──────┘    └─────┘
               │
               │
          ┌────┴─────┐
          │ NAT DHCP │
       ┌──┤  Router  ├──┐
       │  └──────────┘  │
       │                │
    ┌──┴──┐          ┌──┴──┐
    │  X  │          │  B  │
    └─────┘          └─────┘
```

- `S` is the VPN server and it's accessible on the internet via static IP;
- `X` is a "compute server", it can access the internet, but is behind a NAT and it's IP is dynamic and not known in advance;
- `A` is a "remote client" that wants to connect to `X`;
- `B` is a "local client" that wants to connect to `X` and it's in the same local network.

I want that `A` and `B` can connect to `X` through `S`, but all of these hosts should use the VPN only when contacting each other and not when accessing the internet.

So, for instance, `A` can ping google.com directly, but will ping `X` via `S`.

After searching and reading documentations, it's still unclear to me if it's possible to do this without using `iptables` and if it's possible to do so using only the wireguard configuration.

The current configuration is the following:

```
## S wg0.conf

[Interface]
PrivateKey = S-private-key
Address = 172.9.9.1/24
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
ListenPort = 51820

[Peer]
# A
PublicKey = A-public-key
AllowedIPs = 172.9.9.100/32

[Peer]
# B
PublicKey = B-public-key
AllowedIPs = 172.9.9.101/32

[Peer]
# X
PublicKey = X-public-key
AllowedIPs = 172.9.9.10/32
```

```
# A wg0.conf

[Interface]
Address = 172.9.9.100/24
PrivateKey = A-private-key
DNS = 1.1.1.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = S-public-key
Endpoint = S-ip-address:51820
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
```

`B`'s configuration is similar to `A`, but with IP `172.9.9.101` and different private key.

```
# X wg0.conf

[Interface]
Address = 172.9.9.10/24
PrivateKey = X-private-key
DNS = 1.1.1.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = S-public-key
Endpoint = S-ip-address:51820
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
PersistentKeepalive = 25  # To keep the server reachable
```

This configuration works and all the hosts can access each other via the VPN, but I want that ONLY traffic directed to hosts `172.9.9.*` goes through this VPN. The other traffic shall be routed by the default gateway.

What puzzles me is that, if I change the configuration of `A` so that

```
AllowedIPs = 172.9.9.0/24
```

then, for `A`, the packages are routed as intended (e.g. I can `curl ifconfig.me` and get `A`'s public IP), but if I do the same on `X`, it will not work and packages not going to `172.9.9.0/24` will fail to be delivered.

### EDIT#1

Forgot to mention that I would also love if, when connecting to `X`, the local clients such as `B` would not send packages outside the local network, so `B -> Router -> X` and not `B -> Router -> S -> Router -> X`.

Comment: `AllowedIPs` is the way to go, as Justin explained clearly in their answer. It is possible that you cannot `curl ifconfig.me` when using `AllowedIPs = 172.9.9.0/24` because of DNS issues. Check if you can `ping 8.8.8.8`: if you can, then fix your DNS resolution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `AllowedIPs` to the IP addresses you want to *route to/through the peer*.

In a normal hub-and-spoke configuration, on your hub (S), you'd configure `AllowedIPs` for each peer like you have, routing packets to each peer only if they use the peer's WireGuard IP address as their destination address; and on your spokes (A, B, and X), you'd configure `AllowedIPs` to the CIDR of your WireGuard network (`172.9.9.0/24`), routing packets to the hub only if they use another peer's WireGuard IP addresses as their destination address.

So with a normal configuration, you'd access A from B or X with A's WireGuard IP address of `172.9.9.100`, B from A or X with `172.9.9.101`, and X from A or B with `172.9.9.10`.

But if you also want to be able to access each spoke via the IP address bound to the spoke's physical NIC (eg `eth0`), you'd need to adjust the `AllowedIPs` on both the hub and the spokes to include those IP addresses.

For example, if A's `eth0` address is `198.51.100.65`, B's is `192.168.0.66`, and X's is `192.168.0.88`, you'd adjust the peers in the hub's WireGuard config to this:

```
## S wg0.conf
...

[Peer]
# A
PublicKey = A-public-key
AllowedIPs = 172.9.9.100/32
AllowedIPs = 198.51.100.65/32

[Peer]
# B
PublicKey = B-public-key
AllowedIPs = 172.9.9.101/32
AllowedIPs = 192.168.0.66/32

[Peer]
# X
PublicKey = X-public-key
AllowedIPs = 172.9.9.10/32
AllowedIPs = 192.168.0.88/32
```

And set `AllowedIPs` in each of the spoke's config to this:

```
AllowedIPs = 172.9.9.0/24
AllowedIPs = 198.51.100.65/32
AllowedIPs = 192.168.0.66/32
AllowedIPs = 192.168.0.88/32
```

(Note you can also specify all the blocks on one line like `AllowedIPs = 172.9.9.0/24, 198.51.100.65/32, 192.168.0.66/32, 192.168.0.88/32` if you prefer.)

---

With your current configuration, where you have `AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0` on X, when you run `curl 198.51.100.65` from X, what's happening is that X is routing the packets destined for A (and everything else) through its WireGuard tunnel to S, and then S is routing those packets unencrypted over the Internet to A (masqueraded with S's own public IP address); in response, A sends unencrypted packets over the Internet to S, which S routes through its WireGuard tunnel to X.

If you want to make sure S *doesn't ever* route packets tunneled through your WireGuard network out to the Internet, you can adjust your iptables rules to prevent this; something like the following would probably do the trick:

```
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -o eth0 -j DROP; iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wg0 -j DROP
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation! It is very clear, although regarding the access using the `NIC` IP address, it's still unclear to me: since `X` and `B` are behind DHCP and their IP might change (especially for `B`), I cannot know that in advance and set the appropriate allowed IP.

Comment: Also, I already tried to set the `AllowedIPs` to `172.9.9.0/24`, but didn't work. As it was mentioned in a comment, it was a DNS issue.

Comment: To use DHCP-assigned NIC addresses, you'd either have to configure your DHCP server to assign X and B fixed IP addresses, or update the other peers' `AllowedIPs` settings every time a different address was assigned to X or B. (But also note that you can do a hybrid of this, where you access A via its NIC address, but X and B via their WireGuard addresses -- in that case, you can simply omit X and B's NIC addresses from your `AllowedIPs` settings.)

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with DNS: using `AllowedIPs = 172.9.9.0/24` allowed me to ping `8.8.8.8`, but not `google.com`.

I solved including the interface DNS in the allowed IPs, so I get DNS resolution via VPN, but traffic is not in the VPN:

```
[Interface]
...
DNS = 1.1.1.1

[Peer]
...
AllowedIPs = 172.9.9.0/24, 1.1.1.1/32
```

This doesn't answer the second question I had: if it's possible to make `X` and `B` communicate directly without going through `S`. The other answer helps in understanding that.

##### EDIT

It seems that it works also by dropping the `DNS` field, so it should use the same DNS server for both interfaces.